# Iterating through a MongoDB Object Attribute

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I have a Nestjs Rest API where I'm trying to query an object from MongoDB. This is the code that I'm using in the `services.ts` file.

```
    async findScore(id: string) {
    // Error Handling - Irrelevant to question
    if (!isValidObjectId(id)) return errorRes(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, Messages.NOT_AN_ID)
    
    // Mongoose query to fetch object
    const existingAssessments = await this.assessmentModel.findById(id).lean()

    // Error Handling - Irrelevant to question
    if (!existingAssessments) return errorRes(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, Messages.notFound("ASSESSMENT"))

    // Printing the queried object - THIS WORKS FINE - Prints the entire object
    console.log(existingAssessments)

    // Printing the answers array (array of array of booleans) of the queried object - THIS WORKS FINE - Prints [[true, false]]
    console.log(existingAssessments.answers)


    for (let answerArr in existingAssessments.answers) {
        // Printing the answers in each array of the queried object - THIS PRINTS OUT 0
        console.log(answerArr)
    }
}
```

The output of the console log statements are given below.

[image]

The object that I just queried has an attribute namesd `answers` which is an array of arrays containing boolean values.

In the first console.log statement, I print the entire object. - Works fine

In the second console.log, I print the answers attribute alone. - Works fine

When I iterate over the answers array to print their values, it always prints 0. This should actually print the sub-array containing the booleans.

This is how my Mongo Schema is defined for this attribute

```
answers: {
    type: [
        [{
            type: Boolean
        }]
    ],
    required: false
}
```

And this is how my DTO looks for this attribute.

```
@IsNotEmpty()
@IsArray()
answers: Boolean[][]
```

Please help me print the values in the array of boolean arrays from the queried object in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `for ... of` not `for ... in`

```js
 // Printing the answers array (array of array of booleans) of the queried object - THIS 
 
existingAssessments = { answers: [[true, false]] }
console.log(existingAssessments.answers)


for (let answerArr of existingAssessments.answers) {
    console.log(answerArr)
}
```

[`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops over enumerable property names of an object.

[`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (new in ES6) does use an [object-specific *iterator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) and loops over the values generated by that.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = ['el1', 'el2', 'el3'];

arr.addedProp = 'arrProp';

// elKey are the property keys which in your case is "0"
for (let elKey in arr) {
  console.log(elKey);
}

// elValue are the property values which in your case is array of 
for (let elValue of arr) {
  console.log(elValue)
}
```